# How to break an infinte async loop using observables in f#

Tags: winforms, asynchronous, f#, observable

I want to create a async loop that keep going until the user press the stop button. I am however rather new to f# and unsure how to accomplish this.  Async.AwaitObservable() waits forever on for the users input while Async.Sleep() obviously doesn't take any user input at all.

Any help would be greatly appreciated, my current code look like this:

```
open FSharpx.Control.Observable
open System.Windows.Forms

module Gui =
    let form = new Form(Text="I do loops", TopMost=true,  Width=250,  Height=250)
    let lbl = new Label(Text="loops: 0", Top=10, Left=10)
    let btn1 = new Button(Text="Continue", Top=30, Left=10, Width=60)
    let btn2 = new Button(Text="Stop", Top=60, Left=10, Width=60)
    form.Controls.AddRange [|btn1; btn2; lbl|]

module Main =
    let observables = Observable.merge
                      <| Observable.map (fun _-> 0) Gui.btn1.Click
                      <| Observable.map (fun _-> 1) Gui.btn2.Click

    let rec loop observable n = async{
        Gui.lbl.Text <- (sprintf "loops: %d" n)

        let! somethingObservable = Async.AwaitObservable(observable) 
        match somethingObservable with
            | 0     -> return! loop observable (n+1)
            | 1     -> ()
            | _     -> failwith "Error!"
    }

    Async.StartImmediate(loop observables 0); System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Gui.form)
```

I would like the loop too behave like the one below, while still allowing the user to break the loop. Is that possible?

```
    let rec loop observable n = async{
        Gui.lbl.Text <- (sprintf "loops: %d" n)
        do! Async.Sleep(500)
        return! loop observable (n+1)
```

Comment: Look into CancellationToken

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by Foole in the comments, one way to do this is to use `CancellationToken`. F# asynchronous workflows have a built-in support for cancellation, so if you pass a cancellation token to `StartImmediate` when starting the workflow, you can later cancel the computation by triggering the cancellation of the token.

In your case, you can create a new cancellation token and cancel it when the second button is clicked. Something like this:

```
let rec loop n = async {
  Gui.lbl.Text <- (sprintf "loops: %d" n)
  do! Async.Sleep(500)
  return! loop (n+1) }

let cts = new System.Threading.CancellationTokenSource()
Async.StartImmediate(loop 0, cancellationToken = cts.Token)
Gui.btn2.Click |> Observable.add (fun _ -> cts.Cancel())
```